# Why is there a proposition and why is it "in" in THIS sentence? Why is "be" used other than "should be"? What's the structure of the that-clause?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-structure, clauses

Why is there a proposition and why is it "in" in THIS sentence? Why is "be" used other than "should be"? What's the structure of the that-clause?

**"Moulton’s letter cited the concerns of others *in* asking that the centers *be* shut down."**

I met the sentence when reading "Moulton wants local colleges to cut ties with Chinese institute"(https://www.bostonglobe.com/metro/2018/03/09/moulton-wants-local-colleges-cut-ties-with-chinese-institute/2l5Y9Oa1WgG3SuapqGCaNP/story.html?event=event25?event=event25)

Comment: What research have you done on those items?

Comment: What I don't understand is this sentence: "Moulton’s letter cited the concerns of others in asking that the centers be shut down."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The pattern "[clause] **in** [gerund phrase]" means that the subject does [clause] within the larger context of the subject doing [gerund phrase].  In this case, the meaning is:

> Moulton's letter cited the concerns of others, and with this justification, the letter asked that the centers be shut down.

- "**ask that** [[subjunctive clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)]" is a pattern to describe a request for someone to do something or make something happen.  Compared with other uses of **ask**, this pattern is less common and tends to carry a legalese tone.  It's appropriate here because Moulton's letter seems to have a legal implication.
- **be** is used this way in a subjunctive clause.

The sentence could be rephrased with the more common pattern "**ask for** [subject] **to** [[infinitival clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#To-infinitive)]" as:

> Moulton's letter cited the concerns of others in asking for the centers to be shut down.